# Can one use Markdown in the contact page?

Tags: support, markdown, contact

I wonder whether using Markdown in the contact page (https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) will be properly rendered to the readers.

Comment: No, it's not. I've opened the support tickets resulting from using the form and it was rendered as plain text. If you want formatting, sending a rich text message to `community-support@stackexchange.com` is likely a better option.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks! Feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: Not confident enough to post an answer. Perhaps they're using something on their end to render it.

Comment: The thing is, there's plenty of markdown editors and even in case if it is not supported by the contact form, they can easily paste your message in a editor / viewer and read everything with ease

Comment: What are you planning to do? Send them only a screenshot of your inquiry?

Comment: With how many times the team has switched their tools for organizing these tickets, I don't know if a definite answer is possible. As was noted, the nice thing about Markdown is that it is *designed to be readable even as plain-text*. Therefore, there's no reason to be concerned about using Markdown formatting, even if it doesn't end up rendering on the recipient's end. Obviously, avoid gratuitous overuse of formatting, but that's *especially* true if it is known to render properly.